# where the IBMCloud Classic-Infrastructure EventAPI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'd like to use of "Events" and "Tickets" on IBM portal(new).
We uses old SoftlayerAPI.

Tickets is now try this:
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/case-management

Events API is can not found.

could you tell me where the Classic-Infrastructure Events API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tickets**

*All account tickets*

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getTickets
```

*Specify Ticket*

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Ticket/123456/getObject
```

the 123456 data change with your ticket Id

**Event**

*All account Events*

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event/getAllObjects
```

*Unplanned, planned, announcements event type*

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[notificationOccurrenceEventType]&objectFilter={"notificationOccurrenceEventType":{"keyName":{"operation":"ANNOUNCEMENT"}}}
```

Could you choose the key Name with another event type(PLANNED, UNPLANNED INCIDENT, ANNOUNCEMENT), this will return all events with the type of event that was sent.

**For more references**

*tickets*

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getTickets/

*events*

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event/getAllObjects/

*filters*

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/

I hope it helps you

Comment: Please add a link to the documentation for these APIs.

Comment: Get All tickets.
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getTickets/
get a specific ticket
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/getObject/
get all object occurrence event
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Notification_Occurrence_Event/getAllObjects/
Use the filters
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It is always better to edit the answer then add the links as comments.

Comment: Thank you very much.

It seemed to be removed by my misunderstanding.
Thank you for providing the reference.